# JQuery/Ajax html loads just once

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make a page which shows data in 2 databases in almost real time. The problem i have is that JQuery Ajax call changes html just once

HTML Code:

```
    <div class="database">
    <h1>Trying to connect...</h1>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".database").each(function update()
        {
            var self = this;
            var i = 0;
            $.ajax(
                {
                    url: "/show",
                    method: 'GET',
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        $(self).html(data);
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                }
            )
           setTimeout(update, 10000);
        });
        update();
    </script>
</div>
```

PHP code that runs on /show

```
    try
    {
        $SosAlerts = DB::connection('MSSQLSERVER01')->select('select TOP(10) * from SosAlert ORDER BY date_time DESC');
        echo "<h3>MSSQLSERVER01</h3>
              <table>
        <tr>
                <th>SosAlertID</th>
                <th>XCoordinate</th>
                <th>YCoordinate</th>
                <th>Date And Time</th>
              </tr>";
        foreach ($SosAlerts as $sosAlert) {
            echo "<tr>
                <td> " . $sosAlert->SosAlertID . "</td>
                <td>" . $sosAlert->XCoordinate . "</td>
                <td>" . $sosAlert->ZCoordinate . "</td>
                <td>" . $sosAlert->date_time . "</td>
            </tr>";
        }
    echo "</table>";
    } catch (Exception $e)
    {
        echo "<h1>MSSQLSERVER01 is currently unavailable</h1>";
    }
    try
    {
        $SosAlerts = DB::connection('MSSQLSERVER02')->select('select TOP(10) * from SosAlert ORDER BY date_time DESC');

        echo "<h3>MSSQLSERVER02</h3>
              <tr>
                <th>SosAlertID</th>
                <th>XCoordinate</th>
                <th>YCoordinate</th>
                <th>Date And Time</th>
              </tr>";
        foreach ($SosAlerts as $sosAlert) {
            echo "<tr>
                <td> " . $sosAlert->SosAlertID . "</td>
                <td>" . $sosAlert->XCoordinate . "</td>
                <td>" . $sosAlert->ZCoordinate . "</td>
                <td>" . $sosAlert->date_time . "</td>
            </tr>";
        }
    } catch (Exception $e)
    {
        echo "<h1>MSSQLSERVER02 is currently unavailable</h1>";
    }
```

Issue is that `$(self).html(data)` updates html content of `<div class="database">` just once, the first time a call is made, after that it doesn't change anymore. `console.log(data)` shows that ajax call is made every 10s and data is changed properly when updates to database are made. I.e. i run HTML page,  it show Trying to connect... , after that it changes to table showing 10 rows, and same is shown in console log, in next 10 seconds I insert new row in database, call is repeated, console log shows new row when dumping data, but html is not changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the reference to `self` is getting lost in the function calls.  The first `this` refers to the element from the `.each()` iteration, but I bet on the subsequent calls which are outside of that iteration `this` refers to the function itself.

This approach of having the function call itself is pretty awkward.  Instead, put the operation into its own function and just set that function on an interval:

```
function update() {
    $(".database").each(function () {
        var self = this;
        var i = 0;
        $.ajax({
            url: "/show",
            method: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                $(self).html(data);
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
}
setInterval(update, 10000);
```

That way each call to `update` every 10 seconds will invoke a new call to `.each()` which will in turn set `self` to the target element each time.